# Change "value" of combobox option JS

Tags: javascript, html

So, as the title says I want to change the value of a certain option using JS. I have already looked for it but every answer refers to changing the selected option not the value of a specifical option.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>Ver</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

I want to change "Ver" option value from 0 to 1. I don´t know if it is possible but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried assigning it an id and then changing it in your js file?
Something like this:

```
<option value='0' id='opt1' selected>Ver</option>
```

and in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("opt1").value = "1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the option with value 0 using
`let opt = document.querySelector('select.form-control option[value="0"]')`

You can then change the value by reassigning it
`opt.setAttribute('value', '1')`

If you have more than one `select` with class `form-control` this could be a problem, and you might want to give it/them a unique `id` — then the selector would be
`let opt = document.querySelector('select#your-id option[value="0"]')`

Here is a stack snippet doing this, where I've combined the select and the assignment into a single statement. I've also added a `change` event listener to show the value in the console, so if you switch to 20 then switch to Ver again it would print `20` and then `1` to the console, showing you that the value is indeed `1`, not `0`

```js
document.querySelector('select.form-control')
        .addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            console.log(this.value);
        });

document.querySelector('select.form-control option[value="0"]')
        .setAttribute('value', '1');
```

```css
select {
    min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>Ver</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can assign the value with the following instruction

```
$("#SelectID").val("value option");
document.getElementById("SelectID").value = "value option";
```

reference in this url [Set value of combobox or select](https://estradawebgroup.com/Post/Cambiar-el-valor-seleccionado-en-un-combobox-o-select-con-javascript-y-jquery/4645)